# Git for Windows unattended installation issue

Tags: windows, installation, git

I am trying to install [Git for Windows v.2.33.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.33.0.windows.1/Git-2.33.0-64-bit.exe) in silent mode by following [these instructions](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Silent-or-Unattended-Installation).
Command that I am using:

```
C:\Windows\system32>C:\Installers\Git-2.33.0-64-bit.exe /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh" /LOG="C:\git-for-windows.log"
```

OS: Windows Server 2016.
[winver screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BLwS.png)

I've ran into the following installer error:
[Inno Setup error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A8lp.png)

Inno Setup log file (part with exception message):

```
2021-08-19 10:15:40.281   Installation process succeeded.
2021-08-19 10:15:42.484   CurStepChanged raised an exception.
2021-08-19 10:15:42.484   Exception message:
2021-08-19 10:15:42.484   Message box (OK):
                          Runtime error (at 325:19181):
                          
                          Could not call proc.
2021-08-19 10:15:46.687   User chose OK.
2021-08-19 10:15:46.781   Need to restart Windows? No
2021-08-19 10:15:46.781   Deinitializing Setup.
2021-08-19 10:15:46.817   Log closed.
```

Comment: If only it told you what the user chose OK to... Is there any useful information in the Windows Application event log? Or does omitting the `/VERYSILENT` flag give you more information?

Comment: Try it when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it seems changing /VERYSILENT to /SILENT doesn't show any difference. I've also searched event logs for any clues, but didn't find any errors/warnings that happened during the installation time.

Comment: @harrymc not possible, it's a virtual machine.

Comment: It's quite possible by defining the Linux ISO as the CD of the VM.

Comment: UPD: looks like similar problem has been reported [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3368).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in new Git for Windows version: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.33.0.windows.2

> Bug Fixes
>
> A bug affecting older Windows versions that caused the installer to show the >error message "Could not call proc" was fixed.